React-markdown + remarkMath + rehypeKatex, not working properly once deployed
Previously I was using Markdown  
    "markdown-to-jsx": "^7.4.7",

But this was not supporting the mathematical expressions
I shifted towards
    "react-markdown": "^9.0.1"

along with
    "rehype-katex": "^7.0.1",
    "remark-math": "^6.0.0"

in code i used it like

  const processContent = (content: string) => {
    // Handle tabs
    content = content.replace(/\t/g, '    ');

    content = content.replace(/^(\s*)[*+-] /gm, (p1) => {
      const indentLevel = Math.floor(p1.length / 2);
      const bullet = indentLevel === 0 ? '•' : indentLevel === 1 ? '◦' : '•';
      return `${p1}${bullet} `;
    });
    
    // Remove extra line breaks, replacing double or more newlines with a single one
    content = content.replace(/\n{2,}/g, '\n'); 

    content = content.replace(/\\\[/g, '$$').replace(/\\\]/g, '$$');

    // Wrap standalone LaTeX expressions (e.g., \frac, \pm) with $ for inline math
    content = content.replace(/\\\((.*?)\\\)/g, '$$$1$$'); // Inline math 

    return content;
  };

    <ReactMarkdown
      children={processContent(message.content)}
      remarkPlugins={[remarkMath]}
      rehypePlugins={[rehypeKatex]}
     />

For me I am getting the response in stream and the content is json encoded data that i have to manage the tabs bullet points and spacing
I altered the LaTeX expression with the $ sign
When on local envoirment I tested it was working fine
the response was same as expected like this 
I also made the build and run that having the same rendered data with no issues
the logs for build at terminal were like
npm run build
> front@0.0.0 build
> tsc -b && vite build
vite v5.4.2 building for production...
✓ 1289 modules transformed.
dist/index.html                                           0.60 kB │ gzip:   0.32 kB
dist/assets/KaTeX_Size3-Regular-CTq5MqoE.woff             4.42 kB
dist/assets/KaTeX_Size4-Regular-Dl5lxZxV.woff2            4.93 kB
dist/assets/KaTeX_Size2-Regular-Dy4dx90m.woff2            5.21 kB
dist/assets/KaTeX_Size1-Regular-mCD8mA8B.woff2            5.47 kB
dist/assets/KaTeX_Size4-Regular-BF-4gkZK.woff             5.98 kB
dist/assets/KaTeX_Size2-Regular-oD1tc_U0.woff             6.19 kB
dist/assets/KaTeX_Size1-Regular-C195tn64.woff             6.50 kB
dist/assets/KaTeX_Caligraphic-Regular-Di6jR-x-.woff2      6.91 kB
dist/assets/KaTeX_Caligraphic-Bold-Dq_IR9rO.woff2         6.91 kB
dist/assets/KaTeX_Size3-Regular-DgpXs0kz.ttf              7.59 kB
dist/assets/KaTeX_Caligraphic-Regular-CTRA-rTL.woff       7.66 kB
dist/assets/KaTeX_Caligraphic-Bold-BEiXGLvX.woff          7.72 kB
dist/assets/KaTeX_Script-Regular-D3wIWfF6.woff2           9.64 kB
dist/assets/KaTeX_SansSerif-Regular-DDBCnlJ7.woff2       10.34 kB
dist/assets/KaTeX_Size4-Regular-DWFBv043.ttf             10.36 kB
dist/assets/logo-CLSMEnPG.png                            10.58 kB
dist/assets/KaTeX_Script-Regular-D5yQViql.woff           10.59 kB
dist/assets/KaTeX_Fraktur-Regular-CTYiF6lA.woff2         11.32 kB
dist/assets/KaTeX_Fraktur-Bold-CL6g_b3V.woff2            11.35 kB
dist/assets/KaTeX_Size2-Regular-B7gKUWhC.ttf             11.51 kB
dist/assets/KaTeX_SansSerif-Italic-C3H0VqGB.woff2        12.03 kB
dist/assets/KaTeX_SansSerif-Bold-D1sUS0GD.woff2          12.22 kB
dist/assets/KaTeX_Size1-Regular-Dbsnue_I.ttf             12.23 kB
dist/assets/KaTeX_SansSerif-Regular-CS6fqUqJ.woff        12.32 kB
dist/assets/KaTeX_Caligraphic-Regular-wX97UBjC.ttf       12.34 kB
dist/assets/KaTeX_Caligraphic-Bold-ATXxdsX0.ttf          12.37 kB
dist/assets/KaTeX_Fraktur-Regular-Dxdc4cR9.woff          13.21 kB
dist/assets/KaTeX_Fraktur-Bold-BsDP51OF.woff             13.30 kB
dist/assets/KaTeX_Typewriter-Regular-CO6r4hn1.woff2      13.57 kB
dist/assets/KaTeX_SansSerif-Italic-DN2j7dab.woff         14.11 kB
dist/assets/KaTeX_SansSerif-Bold-DbIhKOiC.woff           14.41 kB
dist/assets/KaTeX_Typewriter-Regular-C0xS9mPB.woff       16.03 kB
dist/assets/KaTeX_Math-BoldItalic-CZnvNsCZ.woff2         16.40 kB
dist/assets/KaTeX_Math-Italic-t53AETM-.woff2             16.44 kB
dist/assets/KaTeX_Script-Regular-C5JkGWo-.ttf            16.65 kB
dist/assets/KaTeX_Main-BoldItalic-DxDJ3AOS.woff2         16.78 kB
dist/assets/KaTeX_Main-Italic-NWA7e6Wa.woff2             16.99 kB
dist/assets/KaTeX_Math-BoldItalic-iY-2wyZ7.woff          18.67 kB
dist/assets/KaTeX_Math-Italic-DA0__PXp.woff              18.75 kB
dist/assets/KaTeX_Main-BoldItalic-SpSLRI95.woff          19.41 kB
dist/assets/KaTeX_SansSerif-Regular-BNo7hRIc.ttf         19.44 kB
dist/assets/KaTeX_Fraktur-Regular-CB_wures.ttf           19.57 kB
dist/assets/KaTeX_Fraktur-Bold-BdnERNNW.ttf              19.58 kB
dist/assets/KaTeX_Main-Italic-BMLOBm91.woff              19.68 kB
dist/assets/KaTeX_SansSerif-Italic-YYjJ1zSn.ttf          22.36 kB
dist/assets/KaTeX_SansSerif-Bold-CFMepnvq.ttf            24.50 kB
dist/assets/KaTeX_Main-Bold-Cx986IdX.woff2               25.32 kB
dist/assets/KaTeX_Main-Regular-B22Nviop.woff2            26.27 kB
dist/assets/KaTeX_Typewriter-Regular-D3Ib7_Hf.ttf        27.56 kB
dist/assets/KaTeX_AMS-Regular-BQhdFMY1.woff2             28.08 kB
dist/assets/KaTeX_Main-Bold-Jm3AIy58.woff                29.91 kB
dist/assets/KaTeX_Main-Regular-Dr94JaBh.woff             30.77 kB
dist/assets/KaTeX_Math-BoldItalic-B3XSjfu4.ttf           31.20 kB
dist/assets/KaTeX_Math-Italic-flOr_0UB.ttf               31.31 kB
dist/assets/KaTeX_Main-BoldItalic-DzxPMmG6.ttf           32.97 kB
dist/assets/KaTeX_AMS-Regular-DMm9YOAa.woff              33.52 kB
dist/assets/KaTeX_Main-Italic-3WenGoN9.ttf               33.58 kB
dist/assets/KaTeX_Main-Bold-waoOVXN0.ttf                 51.34 kB
dist/assets/KaTeX_Main-Regular-ypZvNtVU.ttf              53.58 kB
dist/assets/KaTeX_AMS-Regular-DRggAlZN.ttf               63.63 kB
dist/assets/chat_initial-w4sNP10H.png                    79.35 kB
dist/assets/profile_fallback_image-3r8RM-ky.jpg         114.78 kB
dist/assets/meta-B6fQBcUa.svg                           130.10 kB │ gzip:  78.52 kB
dist/assets/index-AQ_pNyPY.css                           68.00 kB │ gzip:  16.57 kB
dist/assets/index-Bj6-mVt3.js                         1,103.00 kB │ gzip: 349.87 kB
(!) Some chunks are larger than 500 kB after minification. Consider:
- Using dynamic import() to code-split the application
- Use build.rollupOptions.output.manualChunks to improve chunking: https://rollupjs.org/configuration-options/#output-manualchunks
- Adjust chunk size limit for this warning via build.chunkSizeWarningLimit.
✓ built in 8.31s
Note: I dont have CI/CD established now I use to build the project and upload that to s3 for now
But When i deployed that to s3 after the upload was complete I invalidated the cloudfront
the result was not as expected as in the picture

